# Tumblr photoset not responsive on the ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

I'm working on a custom theme on tumblr and I want to make it responsive.

Here's what I came up with so far: [couchspinach.tumblr.com](http://couchspinach.tumblr.com)

My problem is with photosets. I'm using the {photoset} tag.
The [Tumblr docs](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts) say:

> **{Photoset}** Embed code for a responsive Photoset that shrinks to fit the container (max. 700-pixels wide)

I've tested the layout in a few browsers and images are resizing correctly everywhere except on the ipad! Here's a couple of screenshots in landscape mode. The first photoset is ok, the second one not. It happens both on Safari and Chrome for ios.

[image]

[image]

I haven't found much online, [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tumblr-themes/VaTfJWgWDqg) is the only discussion that was relevant to the problem but no solution yet. Anyone knows what it might be? Honestly, I have no idea where to start, I removed the js and that didn't make a difference, same with the css. I'm really at loss at what to do. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bingo!

```
function resizePhotosets(){
    var parentWidth = document.body.querySelector('.html_photoset').offsetWidth; 
    var photosets = document.body.querySelectorAll('iframe.photoset');
    for(var i = 0; i < photosets.length; ++i){
        var photoset = photosets[i];
        photoset.width = parentWidth;
    }   
}
window.onload = resizePhotosets;
window.onresize = resizePhotosets;

// if using Infinite Scroll, call resizePhotosets() in it's callback function.
```

https://gist.github.com/edadams/6678258

Many thanks to Ed Adams.